# How to show a specific amount of images based around a changing Int?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently working on an app that retrieves rewards points from a server.  Depending on how many rewards points available, that many images will show up on the home screen. So if the server returns 5, there should only be 5 images shown. I can retrieve that data ok and have the images set up but am not sure how to only make the total number of images appear based on the number received.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Well how are you retrieving the data? I guess here is my view-point. If you are getting data, what are you storing it in? Once stored, can't you determine the count? Such as `var images:[UIImage] = [ ]` `image.count = 0`   `images.append(UIImage())`   `images.count = 1`

Comment: How do you plan to show the images? An imageView can only show one image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if n is the points retrieved from server:
go through a loop:

```
for i in 0...n {
   // Create one image here
}
```

This will give you required number of images.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your UI layout or how you'd like the images to appear, but you could set up all the images to display and then when a lower number comes in from the server, set some of the images to hidden.

If you are using UIImage then it's really just as easy as

`myImage.hidden = true`